# Rebbe Akivah's background

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

I heard from someone that Rabbi Akiva was a shepherd, a laborer, an am ha’aretz – religious in observance, but ignorant of Torah knowledge. At age 40, he didn’t even know how to read the aleph-beis.

Where can the entire story of Rebbe Akivah background be located?

Comment: You can find Rebbe Akivah's background discussed in his wikipedia page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiva_ben_Joseph#Biography This question does not show even the slightest bit of research effort -1

Comment: @DoubleAA I would agree, but was told on meta that research isn't needed http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3435/1362

Comment: @Danno No, you were told on meta that it is not the case that "[a] good question can not be answered with a link alone."

Comment: Well, Isaac Moses said, "I'm under the impression that there's no "leg work" required here" and my citing the FAQ which expected research was said to be inaccurate on this site ("It's not correct here"). @DoubleAA

Comment: @Danno That was Shokhet not Isaac. You are correct that one user said that, but the voting on your post doesn't indicate any agreement to that claim (rather just disagreement to the claim "[a] good question can not be answered with a link alone") and you thus have no reason to assume community support for it.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, Shokhet, my mistake -- I am not drawing a conclusion based on the downvotes to my answer, but to the responses in the comments which point to a lack of a need for research. Unless there is a counter position that Shokhet is wrong.

Comment: @Danno The downvotes just say that a good question could be answered by link alone, not that there is no need to do and present your own research.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was under the impression that the demand for research, as evidenced by the FAQ was on the questioner and this comment thread was on the nature of the research (not) done when asking. That's why the first comment is on my statement regarding the background to the question. When Isaac Moses speaks of the difficulty of changing the FAQ it seems that he is implicitly agreeing that, as written (demanding research for a good question) is inapplicable on Mi Yodea. That seems to be Shokhet's position as well. You seem to be the other camp. Shouldn't there be a site policy?

Comment: @Danno afaik the faq is site policy till you show me community consensus otherwise. (also i wouldn't be so quick to determine isaac's position from that comment.)

Comment: I don't know if "religious in observance but ignorant of Torah knowledge" is the best or most complete characterization of Rabbi Akiva's prior status as an *'am ha'aretz*. See [*P'sachim* 49b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=49b&format=text): "Rabbi Akiva said: 'When I was an *'am ha'aretz*, I said, "Who will give me a Torah scholar, that I may bite him like a donkey!"'"

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm happy to hear that but I think a meta question is next so I can be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a good summary in [Avot D'Rav Nattan ch 6, mishnah 2](http://www.tsel.org/torah/avotrnatan/index.html#HtmpReportNum0004).

Summarizing some of the story cited there:

He was a shepherd and began learning at 40 years old. Once he passed by a well and noticed a carved stone. He asked who carved this stone, and they told him that it was the water that constantly dripped on it. From this, he said that if water was able to carve a hole in the hard rock, surely the words of Torah could carve his heart.

Immediately, he and his son went to learn at a childrens teacher. He asked the teacher to teach him the Aleph Bet. Eventually, he learned the entir Torah.

Then, he went to learn before R. Eliezer and R. Yehoshua asking them to teach him Mishnah. When they taught him, he would ask, "Why is the letter Aleph written this way, and Bet written this way?" They pushed him aside (because they thaught that he wasn't focusing). However, because Rav Akivah was so curious and exacting on seemingly small details, he developed the unusual talent of revealing and explaining deep secrets that no one else was able to.

Personal note: To me Rav Akivah is a prime example of the adage in Pirkei Avot 4:3:

> [Ben Azai] would say: Do not disparage anyone, and do not shun any thing. **For you have no man who does not have [his] hour**, and you have no thing which does not have a place.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the story of Rabbi  Akiva in both Nedarim [50a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nedarim.50a.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)-b, as well as in Kesuvos [62b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ketubot.62b.15?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)-63a. Avos D'Rabi Nosson ([6-2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avot_D'Rabbi_Natan.6.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) also has the story with some other details filled in.

In English, you can find a historical novel called ["And Rachel was his wife"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0873064887)  written by Marsi Tabak and Ben Zion Sober which recounts and coalesces all the sources pertaining to Rebbe Akiva from the perspective of his wife Rachel.

Comment: The Talmud Yerushalmi in Shabbos 6:1 and Sotah 9:15 also tells the story of Rebbe Akiva. Important note: these three sources (Bavli, Yerushalmi, and Avos de'rebbe nosson)do not tell the same exact story.

Comment: @EiluV'Eilu may i incorporate the sources you provided in my answer?